# Dual Screen in Ubuntu(One inside the other)!

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

I recently migrated to Ubuntu from Windows. And for some strange reason the screen that boots up functions as though there are two different screens on the same monitor. Since I am new to Ubuntu I don't have much knowledge so any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank You!
PS: Visit http://goo.gl/gyXtGr for image

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please explain further what you mean with "One screen inside the other"? I don't think this is clear enough. Also, a bit more information might be necessary to help you. E.g. What graphics card are you using and with which driver?

Comment: @the_Seppi I can't see the image on the OP's link, but his description sounded clearly like an image overlap to me.  He also clearly described misplaced dual windows/screens.  He might have taken more words, but I don't think it could have been much clearer that he had two screens that weren't placed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your **System Settings** controls.  You can get to the screen options to configure your screens by:

- Click on the top right icon in the notification bar (the same one
  used for logging out and turning off the computer.
- Click System Settings
- Click Displays

From there drag your montiors the way they should be.

The controls includes positioning the various monitors, or turning them on or off.  If your system has a bogus one, then use this configuration area to turn off the bogus monitor.

The are other options to get you to better configuration options of your graphics card's features.  Run **Additional Drivers**.

You can get there by typing "Additional Drivers" for search in Ubuntu's launch button.  Select an alternate driver for your graphics adapter.

Comment: @DhruvNarayanArora Youre welcome! Consider putting the check mark to mark the answer solved so that others can benefit.